# Search particular user's timeline tweets by geo location twitter search API

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-search

I am developing an iOS app which includes the search of user's tweets by geo location.

The Twitter search API returns all tweets those matches the particular location.
But i want to search the user's timeline tweets by geolocation.

My sample search URL is

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?adc=phone&count=50&geocode=37.178181%2C-96.054581%2C5794km
```

Anything i am missing here?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you modify your search query by adding one parameter 'q=from:user_name' along with the other parameters you are using in your api at the moment.
This should provide you tweets from user_name in your given geo co-ordinates.
See the documentation for this(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)